# Difference between semi-classical Maxwell Boltzmann Statistics and Boson Statistics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, partition-function

Since semi-classical MB assumes the indistinguishability of particles and Boson Einstein statistics similarly treats degenerate states as indistinguishable states.

What is their difference when calculating the canonical partition function?

Comment: this is relevant https://ps.uci.edu/~cyu/p115A/LectureNotes/Lecture13/lecture13.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In semi-classical Boltzmann statistics, you still a classical Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution which is
$$f(v)dv \propto v^2 e^{-\beta m v^2/2}dv$$
but you divide the partition function by a factor of $N!$ to try and account for indistinguishability.

However, in Bose-Einstein statistics, your distribution function is 
$$\langle n_s \rangle =\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon_s-\mu)}-1}$$
Which accounts for indistinguishability and correctly models the behaviour of bosons at very low temperature, however at high temperature becomes the same as the Maxwell Boltzmann distribution in most cases.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering, how does the indistinguishability in the two statistics differ? For example, consider 3 particles with 3 possible states 1,2,3. n2 = 2, n1=1,n3 =0 counts as one state in both statistics, is that right?

Comment: Notice that in SC statistics the particle is _still_ distinguishable at every single energy level since the factor $g_j^{N_j}$ is still there (compare to $(g_j+N_j-1)!/(g_j-1)!$ for BE).